# Netty ByteBuf occupies all memory

Tags: java, netty, bytebuffer

I wrote a simple code to test the performance my Server

```
        while (true) {
            ByteBuf firstMessage = Unpooled.buffer(8);
            firstMessage.writeInt(1);
            firstMessage.writeInt(1);
            firstMessage.writeLong(1L);
            f.channel().writeAndFlush(firstMessage);
        }
```

After 30 seconds:

- All memory occupied
- Server stop receiving new messages

Sorry my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you are creating new buffers (on-heap) quicker than you can send them across the network on a single channel, so eventually they consume the whole heap and you'll have OOM problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd better try to call `firstMessage.release()` after the flushing is done. In the `ByteBuf` specification, it is shown that the `ByteBuffer` is implementing `ReferenceCounted`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep recreating that buffer. Either release it inside the loop, or create it before the loop starts and just reset it inside the loop.